# Elm 0.18: How to route messages with Sub.map based on their content?

Tags: elm

I have dynamically created Javascript components that communicate via ports with Elm model. They send data through a port of form `port sendData : ((ComponentId, String) ...`

On the elm side there is a `ChildComponent` module that represents their models:

```
type alias ComponentId =
  Int

port sendData : ((ComponentId, String) -> msg) -> Sub msg

type Msg
  = ProcessData String

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
Sub.batch [
  sendData ProcessData
]
```

In the `Parent` I have:

```
update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
  case msg of
    ChildMessage componentId msg -> ...

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
  Sub.batch
    [ Sub.map (ChildMessage componentId) (ChildComponent.subscriptions model.child) ]
```

Obviously this results in

```
Cannot find variable `componentId`

310|     Sub.map (ChildMessage componentId) (ChildComponent.subscriptions (getChildModel (componentId model))) ]
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How do I "extract" `componentId` from data coming from port? Or perhaps what I am doing is completely wrong?

**Update**

I have isolated the problem (with a few additions suggested by @ChadGilbert) into a project https://github.com/lguminski/ElmMultipleComponentsSubscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `Sub.map`, you need a function that accepts a child model as its parameter.  You could instead define `ChildMessage` as

```elm
-- in Parent.elm
type Model =
    ...
    | ChildMessage Child.Model
```

Your parent subscriptions function will need to be updated:

```elm
-- in Parent.elm
subscriptions model =
    Sub.batch
        [ Sub.map ChildMessage (ChildComponent.subscriptions model.child) ]
```

When it comes to handling the data from the port in the child, you will need a `Msg` that has as its first parameter the same type defined in your port, mainly `(ComponentId, String)`. Consider adding something like this to your child, where the new `RouteData` message can then call the `ProcessData` update case when needed, or ignore it otherwise.

```elm
-- in Child.elm
type Msg
  = ProcessData String
  | RouteData (ComponentId, String)

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
Sub.batch [
  sendData RouteData
]

update msg model =
    case msg of
        RouteData (componentId, val) ->
            if componentId == "my-component-id" then
                update (ProcessData val) model
            else
                model ! []
        ProcessData val -> ...
```

**Update**

Based on your additional detail, I would propose that you move the port and child Msg routing out of the Child module and into the Parent. You could then add the following update cases to the Parent:

```elm
ChildMessage componentId childMessage ->
    let
        childUpdates =
            List.map (\c -> if c.id == componentId then updateChild c else c ! []) model.children

        updateChild child =
            let
                (updatedChildModel, cmd) =
                    Child.update childMessage child
            in
                updatedChildModel ! [ Cmd.map (ChildMessage child.id) cmd ]

    in
        { model | children = List.map Tuple.first childUpdates }
            ! (List.map Tuple.second childUpdates)

RouteData (componentId, val) ->
    update (ChildMessage componentId (Child.ProcessData val)) model
```

[I have created a pull request for your repository here](https://github.com/lguminski/ElmMultipleComponentsSubscription/pull/1)

Comment: thanks! @ChadGilbert we are almost there. The only problem is that there are multiple children, so `model.child` cannot be provided upfront like you suggested. It also needs to be calculated dynamically based on the message. I created https://github.com/lguminski/ElmMultipleComponentsSubscription to illustrate this.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a slight modification in your design, as well as created a pull request to your code with a working example.

Comment: Thanks @ChadGilbert . I can see that you elevated child-specific communication (port & subscriptions) to the level of parent and process it there. Actually this is what I tried to avoid as I perceive this as a leak of Child abstraction. I hoped there is a way to encapsulate all of this in Child. But perhaps it is not possible. Let my question be open for a few days, and if nobody comes up with better idea, I will accept you answer as a valid workaround. Thanks again.

Comment: Moving port with child's communication to parent breaks child's abstraction but works. So it's not an answer to the original question, but a valid workaround. Anyway accepting. Thanks @ChadGilbert for help.